# Dynamic proxy_pass by ip address doesn't work in nginx

Tags: nginx

dear

I was trying to make nginx get upstream ip address from redis server. I put the ip address (192.168.1.223) into an nginx variable $target and I put following proxy_pass in my nginx configuration file:

```
    proxy_pass http://$target;
```

Still, I got the error log:

```
2014/12/17 06:45:02 [error] 13514#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve 192.168.1.223
```

This looks confusing to me, as I already gave ip address and it shouldn't require a resolver. Is there a way to workaround this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There is a new line in the end of my "$target" variable which caused the dns resolve process. The resolver is not required any more after I removed the trailing new line.

Thanks a lot!